# Can graphfana use json data from a web page?

Tags: json, grafana

I have a server that creates a web page with a JSON, made from a temperature monitoring application. I would like to know if there is any way for Grafana to monitor this data and make a dashboard.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the [SimpleJSON](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource) datasource plugin.

However, you have to add a REST endpoint to you web service to send the data in the JSON structure the plugin expects.